# Where to find information on custom USB descriptor types

Tags: usb

Reading configuration data (GET_DESCRIPTOR operation with 0x200 wValue) from a USB device I get a descriptor block with descriptor type 0x22. I can't quite find out what it is.

Descriptor block (immediately follows interface descriptor): `14,22,00,01,13,81,1d,00,17,01,02,08,13,01,0c,00,0c,01,02,08`

So, can anybody please let me know what it is, but more importantly, where should I normally go and find information for custom type descriptors shall I ever come across some other descriptor type?

Comment: the question is genuine and the information is not very known.

Comment: one who downvoted the question earlier is either do not understand USB or is doing nuisance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish I had recorded exactly the search path on how I stumbled upon this explanation, as it took me quite a while, and @KuldeepSinghDhaka help to re-trace my steps. It's somewhat sneaky on the part of the USB spec, as it's a bit non-obvious.

I'm using [USB 2.0 Spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/) for reference, the section numbers in later versions may not match.

From [USB 2.0 Spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/), sec 9.4.3
wValue of 0x200 means the request is for standard (or first, low byte of 0), configuration descriptor (high byte 0x2)

From [USB 2.0 Spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/), sec 9.5

> If the class or vendor specific descriptors are independent of
>   configuration information or use a non- standard format, a
>   GetDescriptor() request specifying the class or vendor specific
>   descriptor type and index may be used to retrieve the descriptor from
>   the device. A class or vendor specification will define the
>   appropriate way to retrieve these descriptors.

From [USB Common Class Specification says](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/usbccs10.pdf), sec 3.11:

> The most significant bit of the bDescriptorType field is reserved for future use. 
>   ...
>   The next two most significant bits of the bDescriptorType field are used to indicate standard, class or
>   vendor-specific descriptors. These bits use the same encodings as the bmRequestType.Type field of a
>   USB device request setup packet. Because the upper three bits of the bDescriptorType field are used as
>   described above, the maximum number of unique descriptors that may be defined for any category
>   (standard, class or device-specific) is 32

Here is how I interpreted the above, and applied it to what I was seeing coming out of (some M$) device.

The descriptor type has a defined structure of:

- bit 7: reserved 0
- bits 6..5:

  - 0 : standard
  - 1 : class
  - 2 : vendor
  - 3 : reserved
- bits 4..0 : descriptor ID

So, the descriptor type 0x22 means : class specific descriptor ID 2.

So, once you see a non-standard descriptor type, check if it's vendor-based, then you will need to find vendor documentation. If it's class based, then check the class of the interface(*) descriptor. If the interface descriptor uses a standard class (e.g. HID), then look up the corresponding standard documentation. If the interface descriptor uses a vendor class, then, again, vendor documentation is needed to understand what the descriptor contents are.

(*) A descriptor may be applicable to the device, or to an interface. My understand is, if a descriptor type is class based, it is applicable to the class of either the device or interface, based on its position.

Comment: Can you please cite the source of information (esp: the bit layout of descriptor type).

Comment: I will love to read the original specs. please mention the link to the document and the relevant secion(s) in the answer.

Comment: If the document and specs come out to be true, i will be amazed. i have never read any doc that describe the bit-layout of descriptor-type. im waiting... :) (and im skeptic too..)

Comment: Finally looks like i got it. [usbccs10.pdf](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/usbccs10.pdf) "Universal Serial Bus Common Class Specification"  "3.11 Identifying Class and Vendor-Specific Requests and Descriptors"

Comment: @KuldeepSinghDhaka thank you for your help. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try some USB analyzers like USBview,Ellysis visual USB analyser which will useful for clear your doubts