hid_open() fails with error "No HID devices with requested VID/PID found in system" when `lsusb -d vid:pid` shows device
Overview
Cannot pair a knock of PS3 controller with sixaxispairer with differing VID / PID for the HID device. Debian 12. Running HID open returns no HID device even though it is listed with lsusb. I have tried this with sudo as well.
Details
I am trying to set the default pairing bluetooth device MAC address of a knock off PS3 controller.
To do so I am modifying: https://github.com/user-none/sixaxispairer/blob/db4c55d1719c95c08b35a5feac4945bf1d3ac7b7/main.c#L28-L32 to hunt for the correct VID, PID specified.
The device shows up on my Debian machine as such:
jambox@kdozer:~$ lsusb -vd 045e:028e

Bus 001 Device 069: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x028e Xbox360 Controller
  bcdDevice            5.72
  iManufacturer           1 Nintendo Co., Ltd.
  iProduct                2 XBOX 360 For Windows
  iSerial                 3 000000000001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0030
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass     93 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  10 21 10 01 01 24 81 78 00 00 03 13 02 00 03 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               8

The failure takes this form when run:
jambox@kdozer:build$ sudo ./sixaxispairer 
Trying: v: 0x45e, p: 0x28e
No HID devices with requested VID/PID found in the system.
Trying: v: 0x45e, p: 0x42f
No HID devices with requested VID/PID found in the system.
Could not find SixAxis controller

I am not sure what I am missing, maybe it has to do with the unrecognized bytes? Any help would be appreciated :)
My Code (to show I'm not doing anything to silly hopefully)
https://github.com/JCohner/sixaxispairer/blob/6d4ec360a95d72be64185de66427e8bc8782d6f7/main.c#L120-L141
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    hid_device *dev;

    if ((argc != 1 && argc != 2) ||
        (argc == 2 && (strncmp(argv[1], "-h", 2) == 0 || strncmp(argv[1], "--help", 6) == 0))) {
        printf("usage:\n\t%s [mac]\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(PRODUCT) / sizeof(*PRODUCT); i++) {
        wchar_t buffer[50];
        swprintf(buffer, 50, L"Trying: v: %#x, p: %#x\n", VENDOR, PRODUCT[i]);
        wprintf(buffer);
        dev = hid_open(VENDOR, PRODUCT[i], NULL);
        wprintf(hid_error(NULL));
        wprintf(L"\n");
        if (dev != NULL) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (dev == NULL) {    
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find SixAxis controller\n");
        return 0;
    }


I think the unrecognised bytes are harmless. They seem to be a vendor (i.e. Microsoft) specific descriptor type from 1998 that didn't go anywhere. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464269/where-to-find-information-on-custom-usb-descriptor-types
